# How to store many dictionary and access it

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I have a socket connection say client and server. So i am sending data from client to server and in server side, i am storing it as dictionary as key and value pair. But i am not sure how to stack up. 
For ex: I am sending a message 'animal' and i am storing it as     my_dict={a:b} where a is the message and b is the ip address associated with it. So what i want is, if i send a message as 'human'. I want to store the message and ip address. but when i print my_dict it always gives the last message i sent. I actually want to print the whole set of dictionaries which was stored. i want to print 'animal':ip and 'human':ip.

I want to access this dictionary like assuming the animal as topics and ip as the connecting ip address for the communication. (Pub-sub)

server side:

```
    def bd_recv(host,port):
        my_dict=dict()
        #listening bd for other devices and controllers
        sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        address=host,port
        sock.bind(address)
        msg,client=sock.recvfrom(4089)
        a=msg.decode()
        b=client[0]
        my_dict={a:b}

        for key,value in my_dict.items():
            print (key)
    def pub-sub():
       context = zmq.Context()
       sub=context.socket(zmq.SUB)  # Note.
       #for the animal topic here i will refer to dictionary. if this animal topic is there i will take that key and value(ip) and append that to the variable ip here.
       sub.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'animal:')  # Note.
       ip=# here comes the value for animal which is ip.
       sub.connect('tcp://ip:8000')
       for i in range(2):
       print('Received: %s' % sub.recv())

    if __name__=="__main__":
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=bd_recv, name='broadcast_receive', args=(bd_of_the_machine, 9289))
        threads=threading.Thread(target=pub-sub)
        t1.start()
        threads.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `my_dict` variable everytime you receive a message, so only the last one will be saved. Try changing that line to

```
my_dict[a] = b
```

Also your dictionary need to be declared outside the function body:

```
my_dict = {}

def bd_recv(host,port):        
    #listening bd for other devices and controllers
    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    address=host,port
    sock.bind(address)
    msg,client=sock.recvfrom(4089)
    a=msg.decode()
    b=client[0]
    my_dict[a] = b

    for key,value in my_dict.items():
        print (key)
```

Comment: Then how do i print them?

Comment: The print loop is fine, if you append to the dictionary instead of reassigning

Comment: I printed the my_dict outside the thread and it returns just {}

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you have to make a dict in scope that's outside the `bd_recv` and for example in `bd_recv` you have to return a dict {a:b} which you should add to that dict

Update:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

total_dict = {}

def bd_recv(host, port):
    global total_dict
    while True:
        my_dict=dict()
        #listening bd for other devices and controllers
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        address=host,port
        sock.bind(address)
        msg,client = sock.recvfrom(4089)
        a = msg.decode()
        b = client[0]
        my_dict = {a:b}
        total_dict.update({a:b})

        for key,value in my_dict.items():
            print (key)

def print_all_animals():
    while True:
        print(total_dict)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(
        target=bd_recv,
        name='broadcast_receive',
        args=("0.0.0.0", 9289)
    )
    t2 = threading.Thread(
        target=print_all_animals,
        name="print_all_animals",
        # args=()
    )
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

But I don't think using global variable is good solution but you didn't give any more context or mockup. In most scenarios queue with some kind of locking storage would be better and more "sure". It all depends on how do you want to access this dict in your code and you didn't provided that.

Comment: the problem is i am using threads. I am not sure how to access it outside so let me completely update the question

Comment: Where do you need to use this dict ? Inside a thread or outside, I can't tell from the code. You can either create loop in the thread or communicate with a thread with queue like this https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/27/python-threads-communication-and-stopping

Comment: My idea is to refer to this dictionary for other functions which i will define later.

Comment: in your example you have to add `queue` as an argument for `bd_recv` and after t1.start make a loop for collecting all data and put them in some unified dict. It should be enough in your example. lmk if that solves it

Comment: The idea sounds valid. But i will try my best to do that. I had bad time creating queue once.

Comment: I tried but i am missing something which is not queuing up. Could you please post your solution with queue.

Comment: Yes, but please post some, even mockup, code what you're doing with this dict because I don't know how are you going to use it. One option I see is that you are collecting animals in one thread and doing something with them in another ( or perhaps few threads ). Other option is that you're collecting all input in threads and then doing something with it.

Comment: I am going to store them in a dictionary or a queue to access the message and IP address associated with it in other function for reference. For instance if I store animal:IP address then for other function I need this animal key and it's ip address to connect to it and do a pub-sub. I'm gonna use this animal as my topic filter in one of my function. This is because I am getting so many inputs from different clients. So I need to differentiate.

Comment: was it something like you wanted ?

Comment: I will test this soon and i hope it works. To answer what i was going to do is as i said  i want to use this store dict as my topic and ip for communication pattern pub-sub. So in another thread i will look into the store dictionary for example 'Animal':Ip , 'Human':ip then i want to subcribe to the topic 'Animal' and i will use that ip address for connecting. This is the idea i am gonna use this dict for. @qocu and By the way thanks for the support.

Comment: please check the updated question for the mock up you used how i wanna use dictionary.

Comment: I guess you want to make something like {'animal': "IP1 IP2 IP3"} if animal came from some ip but the code is written that I can't understand much more of it. You put ZeroMQ all of a sudden there and I can't see where you are actually using animal and ip in pub-sub(). Anyway you should be ok using my solution ( kindof ) where you put zeromq in print_all_animals function or better - use Queue between your pub-sub() and bd_recv(). I still don't know if you want ot have dict of all animals in python or in ZeroMQ. I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve so can't help you more.

Comment: i have two devices with different ip and i am sending messages from each device to one server. So one msg is 'animal' and other msg is 'bird' from other device. Now i will store these msg along with its ip address in a dictionary and i assume these are my topics. so i will use pub-sub from server and i will subscribe to these topics and do communication.

Comment: which would be {'animal':ip} and {'bird':ip}, i will not use the same msg for different ips.